# onFailedToReceiveAd(Invalid Ad Request) - cannot get AdMob to show banners

Tags: android, admob

I have added AdMob banner into my application according to a how-to. But banner is never shown, i have made this the same way i did with another app and everything works perfectly. Cannot find a solution, checked all the related Stack questions, nothing works:(
I use a correct publisher id and i have added GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar

My xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.80" >
    </ListView>
 <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   ads:adUnitId="pub_id"
   ads:adSize="BANNER"
      ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>     
</LinearLayout>
```

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.luckyyou.greatlaces"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.luckyyou.greatlaces.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
 android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
 android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|  smallestScreenSize"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.luckyyou.greatlaces.tab1"
            android:label="@string/name1" 
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">  </activity> 

                 ...

             <activity
            android:name="com.luckyyou.greatlaces.tab12"
            android:label="@string/name12" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">  
            </activity>

    </application>

 </manifest>
```

Here what LogCat says:

```
01-08 14:21:52.778: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1804): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 52K, 51% free 2674K/5379K, external 1527K/1559K, paused 242ms
01-08 14:21:55.431: ERROR/ActivityThread(1804): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
01-08 14:21:55.518: INFO/Ads(1804): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
01-08 14:21:55.858: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1804): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads-143252855.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
01-08 14:21:56.198: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1818): DexOpt: load 64ms, verify+opt 75ms
01-08 14:21:56.378: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1804): DexOpt: --- END 'ads-143252855.jar' (success) ---
01-08 14:21:56.378: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1804): DEX prep '/data/data/com.luckyyou.greatlaces/cache/ads-143252855.jar': unzip in 34ms, rewrite 520ms
01-08 14:21:56.378: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1804): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 217K, 50% free 2876K/5639K, external 2151K/2316K, paused 140ms
01-08 14:21:56.388: DEBUG/webviewglue(1804): nativeDestroy view: 0x91621b8
01-08 14:21:56.748: INFO/Ads(1804): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"session_id":"9030672260837145206","seq_num":"1","slotname":"pub_id","u_w":320,"msid":"com.luckyyou.greatlaces","cap":"m,a","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1","bas_off":0,"net":"ed","app_name":"1.android.com.luckyyou.greatlaces","hl":"en","gnt":3,"carrier":"310260","u_audio":4,"kw":[],"u_sd":1.5,"simulator":1,"ms":"aESYziECsoJ_gzwNWoDn5OQjNPknVakDj2SrrKXxrOZsEWD6r4wsETa7CzeB3sCAwMmoFdWVd-PB3S-s381WQrdDEK_k05alE8tfJmkHWXNzJkS-Xql-6WqEEAgBc0-8cSp08YlmRv0xjgqH5yKehnOHMtOonYftI2DXsmFuMAwdjIOmWmCYaT7BjDQDlUzULzTvZRe6EvgSgalmiK-4Wfem4vJyo-QXzVRVG5Ng0WRcCebjE0LIulSyCsQyngqLWg2VhqUfHzGfiru4NxSUYV3GvxksLLXeShEv8X00-c629-Loha16sjyWYc0ecQ9gerTls_FvObQwTYyTb3jqRg","isu":"B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB","format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":0,"y":76,"x":0,"width":0},"u_h":533,"pt":1,"bas_on":0,"ptime":0});</script></head><body></body></html>
01-08 14:21:56.918: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1804): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 128K, 49% free 2886K/5639K, external 2438K/3005K, paused 108ms
01-08 14:21:57.550: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1804): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 49% free 2885K/5639K, external 4395K/5489K, paused 126ms
01-08 14:21:58.507: DEBUG/gralloc_goldfish(1804): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-08 14:21:59.218: INFO/ActivityManager(858): Displayed com.luckyyou.greatlaces/.MainActivity: +7s494ms
01-08 14:22:00.818: WARN/webcore(1804): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
01-08 14:22:00.998: WARN/Ads(1804): Invalid unknown request error: Cannot determine request type. Is your ad unit id correct?
 01-08 14:22:00.998: DEBUG/webviewglue(1804): nativeDestroy view: 0x915dbd0
 01-08 14:22:01.008: INFO/Ads(1804): onFailedToReceiveAd(Invalid Ad request.)
 01-08 14:22:05.238: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1131): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9K, 52% free 2662K/5511K,         external 1527K/1559K, paused 149ms
```

Comment: Is the layout the same as that of the "working" app?

Comment: If you just added the app to AdMob and the publisher id is new, AdMob won't server ads right away. It takes a while for ads to start showing up.

Comment: @Nana Yes, they are the same

Comment: @YasmaniLlanes I am trying to solve this problem for almost 4 days, so I guess it is not the thing.

Answer (score 0):

These look to be the relevant lines in the log.

Since your layout looks OK I suspect that you have do something funky in the theme you have applied for the application that is causing confusion with the view width. Review your @style/AppTheme config.

```
01-08 14:22:00.818: WARN/webcore(1804): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout 
01-08 14:22:00.998: WARN/Ads(1804): Invalid unknown request error: Cannot determine request type. Is your ad unit id correct?
```

The final thing: You said you are using Admob-6.4.1. Are you also using thge GooglePlayServices library? If so you might have inadvertently used some of the Admob classes from GPS. If this is the case then I suggest removing Admob-6.4.1 and going 100% with GPS.

Comment: @Wiliam Well, I do not use GooglePlayServices library and here is my styles.xml:  <resources>
 
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">    
    </style>
    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">   
    </style>
 </resources>